# How to get Order in SenderBuilder class?

Tags: magento2

I override the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder` class in my Magento 2. I want to load some order data but I am not getting anything.

Code :

```
<?php
namespace Customisation\OrderEmail\Model\Order\Email;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderByStore;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    protected $templateContainer;
    protected $identityContainer;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    private $transportBuilderByStore;

    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        TransportBuilderByStore $transportBuilderByStore = null,

    ) {
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
        $this->identityContainer = $identityContainer;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->transportBuilderByStore = $transportBuilderByStore ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            TransportBuilderByStore::class
        );
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $transportBuilder, $this->transportBuilderByStore);

    }

    public function send()
    {
        //$custom_email = 'test@gmail.com';
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->configureEmailTemplate();

        $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
        );

        $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();

        if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
            }
        }

        if($email){
            $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($custom_email); // Added for add BCC for custom dynamic email address
            $logger->info($email);
        }

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

I want to get order data in this send(). How can I get order id or Order in this function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be order instance in the template variables.

```
$vars = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars();
$order = $vars['order'];
```

Might be slightly different depending on the version you are running. Check the `prepareTemplate` method in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender` class.

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting following error
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method getTemplateVars(). My magento version is 2.3.2

Comment: I've updated the answer. @DavidCoder

Comment: Now getting error: Call to a member function getOrder() on array

Comment: getting above error in $order = $vars->getOrder(); line

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was DataObject for some reason.

Comment: Yes Thank you !

Comment: Thanks very much for your help here. I was wondering how to retrieve the order for days.